# What is the equivalent of the following from Magento 1?

Tags: magento2

What is the equivalent of the following from Magento 1

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are asking for. Just from the above question the equivalent class for `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http` would be `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`.

You can find this class in your vendor dir.

`<magento_rood_dir>/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php`

Comment: Hi Priyank. i suspected it might be this class. let me check it out and come back to you. thank you for prompt reply